# Button Onclick is does not hit the submit Function in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm working a nextjs project.

I create a form with button.
when I click the button the form should submit.

But in my case, Onclik is not works.

Here is my code

```
                                    <Button
                                        variant="outlined"
                                        color="primary"
                                        id="BookinEnquireCloseBtnDesktop"
                                        type="submit"
                                        onClick={handleSubmit(onCardSubmit)}
                                    >
                                        Submit
                                    </Button>
```

```
 const {
       handleSubmit,
       register,
       formState: { isSubmitting },
   } = useForm<IPaymentForm>({
          defaultValues: {
               amount : 20,
               description : "demo"
          },
       resolver: yupResolver(paymentSchema),
       mode: 'all',
   });
```

```
    const onCardSubmit = async (value: IPaymentForm): Promise<void> => {
     console.log("hit");

        const paymentDto: PaymentDto = {
            paymentRequest: {
                amount: value.amount,
                description: value.description,            },
        };
    };
```

Edit:

I tried this

```
  <form
                                    onSubmit={handleSubmit(onCardSubmit)}
                                >
<Button

                                        variant="outlined"
                                        type="submit"
                                        disabled={isSubmitting}
                                    >
                                        {!isSubmitting ? 'Submit' : <CircularProgress />}
                                    </Button>

</form>
```

This also does not hit onCardSubmit() funtion.

Comment: A `<button />` of type "submit" will trigger its associated form element's `onSubmit` handler. [Here are the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type). You should move the `handleSubmit` call to the `<form>` element.

Comment: Hi,  I have tried as you said. But that also does not work See my edited Question

Comment: Where do `useForm` and `Button` come from?

Answer (score 0):

I think you handle on Click on Button, but instead of handling form data on the form on Submit event like following:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <input {...register("firstName")} />
  <p>{errors.firstName?.message}</p>
    
  <input {...register("age")} />
  <p>{errors.age?.message}</p>
  
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, Please see my edited question. I have tried as you said